# Isomorphisms between $\Bbb R^n$ and fields

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory

Are there real vector spaces with dimension $\geq 3$ that are isomorphic to a field? I case $n=2$ there are the complex numbers and for $n=3$ the quaternions are non-commutative.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $\dim_\Bbb R(\Bbb H)=4$, not $3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A vector space cannot be isomorphic to a field (they are two different types of structures) but you *could* ask how many finite dimensional $\Bbb R$ algebras there are which are division rings or fields.

It turns out there are only three possibilities for division rings: $\Bbb R$, $\Bbb C$ and $\Bbb H$. The case of $\Bbb H$ corresponds to $n=4$, not $3$. There is nothing for $3$, and nothing above $4$. If you want the $\Bbb R$ algebra to be a field, there are only the two possibilities $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb C$.

The result that says $\Bbb R$, $\Bbb C$ and $\Bbb H$ are the only finite dimensional $\Bbb R$-division algebras is the [Frobenius theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_theorem_(real_division_algebras)). There are many extensions of this theorem. One such extension allows the division algebra to be nonassociative, and it scoops up the $8$-dimensional [octonions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octonion) in addition to these three. (But it doesn't get any more than that!)